# Has one relationship depend on rules

Tags: php, laravel, model, relationship, rules

Is there any way to make has one relation ship between 1 model to one of two different models depend on `rule_id` like :

```
 if($this->rule_id==1)
     return $this->hasOne('App\model2');
 else
     return $this->hasOne('App\model3');
```

if you have better way or this works somehow just notice me thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give a little context to your question? If you're able to tell us what you're actually trying to achieve rather than just using an abstract example, it might help us point you in the right direction. What you're after seems like it *could* be solved using [polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) but I can't be sure.

Comment: @Jonathon hey thanks for your responding I am trying to make a general model that all users can be in then the extra or additional fields of that user can take it from other model depend on his rule.

Comment: Just to add to the above comment, you can have a `morphOne` instead of a `morphMany` relationship as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can build a custom function in your model like this with parameter for checking it

```
public function test($val){
    if($val==1)
       return $this->hasOne('App\model2');
    else
       return $this->hasOne('App\model3');
}
```

and then you can call the function in you view

```
$your object data sent from controller ->test(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better declare relationship with both models. sooner or later it will hit both conditions and make relationships with both models. Why not declare with both in the first place ?

Comment: because the user can be admin or user and all those has different extra fields depends on his rule.

Comment: then make different tables and models for both and declare relationship properly